# How to know the mail size BEFORE sending it

Tags: gmail

I know how to search for received mails with the operator `larger:xM`, but my issue is different.

I have embedded pictures in the mail I want to send and while making it, I have to make sure it doesn’t exceed 8MB because many e-mail service providers of my recipients will refuse the mail as it is too big.

How can I know the mail size **before** sending it?

Comment: Does it help to save your email as a draft, and then search for it?

Answer (score 5):

After attaching the pictures save the email as a draft, which probably has happened several time while writing and attaching the email.

Now search for it using **larger:8m label:draft**.

If it is larger than 8M it will show up in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Select all the attachemnts. Right Click. Click on properties. See the size under " Size" field. As simple as that.

Comment: the value of "size on disk" is related to the block size of the hard drive. You should use Size.